# Syntax issue when trying to rewrite a Jquery plugin from version 1.5 to version 3.3

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-1.5, jquery-3

I found [this JQuery plugin](https://tympanus.net/Tutorials/MicroGalleryImproved/) that looks pretty good for my project. But sadly, it was written way back in [2010](https://tympanus.net/codrops/2010/04/26/improved-micro-image-gallery-a-jquery-plugin/), and it can't work with JQuery 1.6+.

As the source code isn't very long, I've then decided to rewrite it to make it works with JQuery 3.3.1 which I use. But I got stuck very quickly because there is a redundant syntax that I don't know and don't understand :

```
$('<div/>',{
                className   :   'description',
                html        :   descHTML
            });
$images = $('.images',$mg);
$('.images div:visible:last',$this);
...
```

What does this syntax means ? I used to know the selector syntax `$(selector)` without comma in between, but not `$(syntax1, syntax2)` with comma `","` !!!

Please what does that syntax means and how could I reproduce it with JQuery 3.3.

Comment: Well, the first block is making a new `div` element, but not doing anything with it, so that's weird.  The second operation is finding all the elements with a class of `images` in whatever `$mg` references.  And the last one is doing something similar.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery-selector-context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(selector, parentSelector|parentObject);
```

This format of a selector is used to find elements within another element.  `$(selector)` is shorthand for `$(selector, document)`.  If you give a second parameter to the selector, it will use that as the context it searches in, rather than the global `document`.

Ref. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery1

Comment: So with which syntax I could replace `$(selector, parentSelector|parentObject)` in JQuery 3. I thought about `$(parentSelector|parentObject).find(selector)`. It is correct ?